# IBM Rhapsody containers, need algorithms similar to STL

Tags: c++, stl, rhapsody

I am using IBM Rhapsody in C++ and I often need to perform a generic algorithm on Rhapsody containers like OMCollection, OMList or OMMap similar to STL's for_each, copy,  remove, count_if, etc etc etc. Is there a custom library or a package to perform this, or is there an  adapter that would allow me to apply STL generics to Rhapsody container ?
I want to be able to write something along the lines of:

`OMList<OMString> myStringList;
 for_each(myStringList.begin(),myStringList.end(),myFoid);`

without having to use STL containers in Rhapsody.

Comment: Take a look at the source code for one of the algorithms.  Most are trivial to write.  If your containers support iterators, they STL algorithms may actually work with them.

Comment: @AnonMail, Rhapsody containers support Rhapsody iterators. Those are very special and unique breed of iterators :(  While somewhat similar to their STL cousins, they do differ significantly. I do find it odd, however, that no one has ever undertaken an obvious task to try and unify those...

Comment: I took a quick look at OMList and saw that it supports iterators.  That's good.  If you can figure out how to obtain an iterator to the start of the container and one to the end of the container you should be able to use STL algorithms.  If not, you could easily write your own algorithms that support operations on an entire container (if that's acceptable).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  We're considering modifying the OM templates in order to support your original question, plus OMList initialization, support the arrow operator and implement begin() and end() for range-based for loops.  The 'auto' keyword fails for OMIterators as well, but that might be a lost cause.

Comment: @JeffLamb well after a bit of soul searching I gave up and switched to STL iterators. I am not sure what the status is right now as I left the organization since then. As I was leaving there were plans in the works to abandon Rhapsody altogether due to its limitations and get back to coding by hand...

Comment: We're using STL containers/iterators as well, but the code size hit is pretty extreme.